# Owned type property not being populated -EF Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following entities:

**ProjectGroup.cs**

```
//Parts omitted for brevity
public class ProjectGroup : Entity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private HashSet<Project> _projects;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Project> Projects
        => this._projects.ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

**Project.cs**

```
//Parts omitted for brevity
public class Project: Entity<int>
{
    private HashSet<Task> _backlog;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Task> Backlog
        => this._backlog.ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

**Task.cs**

```
//Parts omitted for brevity
public class Task : Entity<int>
{
    public TaskDescription Description { get; private set; }
}
```

`TaskDescription.cs` is a flat value object that encapsulates properties of interest about `Task.cs`.

I have read/write persistance functionality in place using EF Core 3.1 and SQL Server. Inserting a new `Task` in the `Task` collection of `Project` for a particular `ProjectGroup` works as expected and everything is inserted in the database.

However there is a problem when I'm reading from the database. When I query via EF for a particular project, like below, the `Description` property of each member of the `Task` collection is null, even though there are records in the database.

```
var projectGroup = await this.All()
                             .Include(g => g.Projects).ThenInclude(p => p.Backlog).ThenInclude(t => t.Description)
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.Id == projectGroupId);

var project = projectGroup.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == projectId);
```

`this.All()` is `dbContext.Set<ProjectGroup>()`

This is the EF configuration for the `Task` entity:

```
builder
       .OwnsOne(t => t.Description, description =>
       {
           description.WithOwner();
       });
```

I initially tried the query without the second `ThenInclude` as I know from the official docs that owned types are by default populated without including them, but as that didn't work I thought I'd try to manually include the type, but to no avail.

Comment: Most likely you are hitting the following EF Core 3.x breaking change [Dependent entities sharing the table with the principal are now optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#dependent-entities-sharing-the-table-with-the-principal-are-now-optional). Not sure what does your `TaskDescription` class contain, but if it is single string value which is `null` in dtabase, then the owned reference will be null as well.

Comment: Interesting, but  the `TaskDescription` class has string and integer properties, which have values for this particular record in the database

Comment: Well, I guess you need to provide small, but full clean console project reproducing the issue (aka [mre]). I can't reproduce it wilt currently provided code, the property loads as expected (w/o `ThenInclude`).

Comment: You're right! I overlooked a null column. All the other columns that map to `TaskDescription` had values, except this one and I guess this null value caused EF not to map the owned type.